# PHP array_push without numeric key

Tags: php, arrays

how do i push new array without numeric key?

```
$array = array('connect' => array('mydomain.com' => 1.99) );
$new_array['mynewdomain.com'] = 2.99;

array_push($array['connect'], $new_array);
```

Currently returning:

```
Array
(
    [connect] => Array
        (
            [mydomain.com] => 1.99
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [mynewdomain.com] => 2.99
                )
        )
)
```

https://ideone.com/VgL67Y

i am expecting the following output:

```
Array
(
    [connect] => Array
        (
            [mydomain.com] => 1.99
            [mynewdomain.com] => 2.99
        )
)
```

Comment: `array_merge($array['connect'], $new_array);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply append element to the array.

```
$array['connect']['mynewdomain.com'] = 2.99;
```

No need to do `array_push()`. Just use `PHP`'s in built constructs to get the job done.

In Built language constructs are more faster than in built functions and custom functions.

Comment: This is more simpler. :)

Comment: finally got the solution.. php.net should just migrate over to SO.. big thank you

Answer (score 13):

Use `+` for this. Try with -

```
$array = array('connect' => array('mydomain.com' => 1.99) );
$array['connect'] += array('mynewdomain.com' => 2.99);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$array['connect'] = array_merge($array['connect'], $new_array);
```