# How do I construct a keyless array like this?

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP I need to dynamically build an array where some elements of the array are keyless.

I have tried [PHP array_push without numeric key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048988/php-array-push-without-numeric-key) with no joy. It is most probably me (It's late here). I just keep getting the wrong structure (It's been a long day).

```php
// This is built dynamically
$metaquery1 = [
  'key' => 'field1',
  'value' => 'value1',
];

// This is built dynamically
$metaquery2 = [
  'key' => 'field2',
  'value' => 'value2',
];

$query = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    $metaquery1,
    $metaquery2,
  ],
];
```

I am expecting: -

```php
$query = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    [
      'key' => 'field1',
      'value' => 'value1',
    ],
    [
      'key' => 'field2',
      'value' => 'value2',
    ],
];
```

But I get: -

```php
$query = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    [0] => [
      'key' => 'field1',
      'value' => 'value1',
    ],
    [1] => [
      'key' => 'field2',
      'value' => 'value2',
    ],
];
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a keyless array, every item in an array has a key.  If you don't specify one, it will assign a numeric index to it - it's still a key.

Comment: (I mean this in a nice way, but I can't think of a way to phrase it without sounding petulant and facetious, so I'll just go ahead and ask it) what would be the point of a keyless array, how would you do anything with it? I'm curious as it's never occurred to me to even try it?

Comment: Have you tried processing the query? Did it not work?

Comment: @DerekGutierrez You are spot on. Try the query! Yes it works. Ok, live and learn! There is no such thing as a keyless array. I did wonder. So, if this is the case, why does PHP 'print' out the array differently depending on how it is built. Why does it appear as keyless when built manually?

Comment: When an array is created it auto indexes if no index is defined (the index is the key). This is why you see [0][1] etc... In your case, no index was defined for the dynamically created arrays so it assigned its own key of [0][1] etc... and your arrays were the value. array() can also represented by square brackets [ ]. So when you use a function such as print_r() you will see php's interpretation of what you coded. The best way to understand PHP is think of it as a translator that translates your instructions. It is an interpreted language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a keyless array.

Your dynamically created array:

```
$query = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    $metaquery1,
    $metaquery2,
  ],
];
```

Is essentially this:

```
$query = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => 'field1',
      'value' => 'value1',
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'field2',
      'value' => 'value2',
    ),
  ),
];
```

Which translates to what you have shown in your last example. And is the correct format to process the meta-query.

Answer (score 3):

All [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP are actually ordered maps. There is no such thing as a value without a key.